# unable to getting memory used percentage from management api

Tags: azure, rest, memory-management, virtual-machine

I  need to get memory used by azure VM, but i am not getting .

**Tried this** [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXXXXXXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/XXXXXXX/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?timespan=2019-03-31T11:30:00.000Z/2020-09-14T11:00:00.000Z&interval=P1D&metricnames=\Memory\%](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXXXXXXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/XXXXXXX/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?timespan=2019-03-31T11:30:00.000Z/2020-09-14T11:00:00.000Z&interval=P1D&metricnames=%5CMemory%5C%) Committed Bytes In Use&aggregation=Average&api-version=2018-01-01&metricnamespace=azure.vm.windows.guestmetrics

**Response I am getting**
{
"cost": 0,
"timespan": "2020-08-14T11:00:00Z/2020-09-14T11:00:00Z",
"interval": "P1D",
"value": [
{
"id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/xxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/\Memory\% Committed Bytes In Use",
"type": "Microsoft.Insights/metrics",
"name": {
"value": "\Memory\% Committed Bytes In Use",
"localizedValue": "\Memory\% Committed Bytes In Use"
},
"unit": "Unspecified",
"timeseries": [],
"errorCode": "Success"
}
],
"namespace": "azure.vm.windows.guestmetrics",
"resourceregion": "westus2"
}

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled the guest-level monitoring for Azure virtual machines then try again.

See - https://docs.bmc.com/docs/capacityoptimization/btco115/collecting-additional-metrics-using-guest-os-diagnostics-890312716.html